# Why did al-Albani grade as authentic the hadith of Asma regarding the permission of showing the hands and face?

Tags: hadith, women, authenticity, awrah

[Islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/23496/hadeeth-about-women-uncovering-their-faces) says that this hadith is weak:

> narrated by Abu Dawood (4104) from al-Waleed from Sa’eed ibn Basheer
> from Qataadah from Khaalid ibn Durayk from ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be
> pleased with her), that Asma’ bint Abi Bakr entered upon the Messenger
> of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) wearing a thin
> dress. The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
> him) turned away from her and said, “O Asma’, when a woman reaches the
> age of puberty, nothing should be seen of her except this and this” –
> and he pointed to his face and hands.
>
> Abu Dawood said: This is mursal; Khaalid ibn Durayk did not meet
> ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her).
>
> This hadeeth is da’eef (weak) and is not fit to be used as evidence.
> The reasons why it is da’eef are as follows:
>
> 1 – Its isnaad is interrupted, as was stated by Imam Abu Dawood (may
> Allaah have mercy on him) when he said, “This is mursal; Khaalid ibn
> Durayk did not meet ‘Aa’ishah.”
>
> 2 – Its isnaad includes Sa’eed ibn Basheer al-Azdi (or it was said
> al-Basri) Abu ‘Abd al-Rahmaan. Some scholars of hadeeth regarded him
> as thiqah (trustworthy), but Ahmad, Ibn Ma’een, Ibn al-Madeeni,
> al-Nasaa’i, al-Haakim and Abu Dawood regarded him as da’eef. (weak).
>
> Muhammad ibn ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Numayr said of him: His hadeeth is to be
> rejected and he does not amount to anything, and he is not strong in
> hadeeth. He narrated munkar reports from Qataadah.
>
> Ibn Hibbaan said of him: He has a bad memory and makes grievous
> mistakes.
>
> Al-Haafiz ibn Hajar said of him: (he is) da’eef.
>
> 3 – Its isnaad includes Qataadah who is mudallis (i.e., gives false
> impressions concerning the narration of the hadeeth) and did not
> clearly state that he heard the hadeeth from another. It also includes
> al-Waleed ibn Muslim of whom al-Haafiz said: (he is) trustworthy but
> he was also mudallis and did not clearly state that he heard the
> hadeeth from another.
>
> These are the faults in the hadeeth because of which the hadeeth was
> judged to be da’eef (weak). See Fataawa al-Lajnah al-Daa’imah,
> Majallat al-Buhooth, 21/68.

Why did al-Albani grade the hadith to be authentic? Generally weak hadith are just disconnected or weak person in it , but this is one of the most weak hadiths.

Comment: First of all, he graded this narration Hasan li Ghayrihi in Sahih at-Targhib (2045), and not Sahih (maybe it is a mistake from Sunnah.com - [Shaykh Albani] said in the mentioned reference: "But he has a witness from the Hadith of Asma bint Umays, and his strengths were established by Al-Bayhaqi and Al-Dhahabi according to the sayings of the Companions, such as Ibn Abbas and Ibn Umar - and it was done during the time of the Prophet (ﷺ) - as I explained it in "Jilbab al-Mar'ati (p. 57-60)."

Comment: Al-Albani's discussion on this hadith can be found in [الرد المفحم](https://ia803405.us.archive.org/21/items/FP63585/63585.pdf#page=79) (page 79 onwards) and [صحيح الترغيب والترهيب](https://shamela.ws/book/171/1092) (Hadith# 2045) and  [إرواء الغليل في تخريج أحاديث منار السبيل](https://ia600304.us.archive.org/2/items/WAQ25781WAQ/erwaa6.pdf#page=203) (Hadith# 1795) etc.

Comment: @harmer ,who was a witnesss of the hadith , whoah , but there are 2 other people who have problems when narrating hadiths, even if the first narrator after Aisha, is reliable ;  can you elaborate

Comment: A witness in this context means another hadith supporting it's content.

Comment: @harmer ; What's the hadith , i don't understand arabic. , just give me the reference i'll look it up on sunnah.com

Comment: Sunan al-Bayhaqi at least isn't translated on sunnah.com how would you be able to check it? Further the qualification of Sai'ds ibn Basher isn't correct as really hardcore hardliners among the hadith scholars such Sho'bah, ibn abi Hathem, ibn 'Ady and others regarded him as trustworthy. Al-Albani even called people claiming that Imam a-Dhahabi reported this negativ qualification in his lisan al-Mizan as liars who are cherry picking from sources without knowing what they do.